# The best way to define a const variable

Tags: c++, static, namespaces, constants

I'm coding with C++ and I want to know the best way to define a const variable.

As my understanding, if I want to define a const variable in cpp file, we can code like this before: `const static int LEN = 5;` And now C++ suggests us using anonymous namespace: `namespace { const int LEN = 5; }`

I don't know how to define a const variable in header file properly.

I've seen some codes in some header files as below:

```
const int LEN = 5;
```

So is this the best way? Why don't we code `const static int LEN = 5;` in header file?

Comment: Where did `static` even come from? Why do you want to use it? `static` is not needed when defining `const` values. What caused your question in the first place?

Comment: @AnT   dude, this is my question... I want to know if we should / could code `const static int LEN = 5` in header file.

Comment: (In order to properly answer a question it is best to know what triggered it in the first place.) No, we shoudn't. Just use `const int LEN = 5;`, regardless of whether it is in header file or anywhere else. Anonymous namespace is also unnecessary. In C++ `const` already includes `static`. No need to spell it out explicitly.

Comment: "The best way", as stated here, is utterly meaningless. It's like asking "what is the best car". It depends. Does one need power, or fuel economy, or looks, or warranty. "The best car" would be very different, depending on the particular requirements. Similarly, the various ways of defining constant variables have their own particular semantics that are aimed at different situation. To figure out "the best way to define a const variable" you need to ***understand*** what the differences are, and what they mean, and then pick "the best way" depending on your specific situation.

Comment: "C++" doesn't suggest anything

Comment: Do you really need a variable? If not, you could just use an enumerator.

Comment: @AnT Saying "`const` already includes `static`" is very bad wording. It may cause misunderstanding if not misconception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm coding with C++ and I want to know the best way to define a const variable.

There is no "best way". It depends.

BTW, ever heard of `constexpr`?

> As my understanding, if I want to define a const variable in cpp file, we can code like this before: `const static int LEN = 5;`

Yes, we can.

Note that things in namespace scope declared with `static` keyword has *internal linkage*.

Also note that I am **not** calling `LEN` a "static variable".

> And now C++ suggests us using anonymous namespace: `namespace { const int LEN = 5; }`

Everything declared in anonymous namespace has *internal linkage*. But I don't think C++ itself makes any suggestion.

> I've seen some codes in some header files as below:
>
> ```
> const int LEN = 5;
> ```

C++ has a special provision that makes namespace-scoped const-qualified variables have *internal linkage* by default, even without `static` specifier.

See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Linkage

Note that it is different from C.

Also note that it does not mean "`const` includes `static`". Thinking in this way is confusing.

> Why don't we code `const static int LEN = 5;` in header file?

Actually, we can. It may even be beneficial due to non-technical reasons. If you think that your audience who reads your code does not know that special provision, a `static` specifier will make clear to your audience that the variable has internal linkage.

Comment: I have a question: why won't `const int LEN = 5;` in header file cause the redefinition error? I think one header file may be include many times.

Comment: @Yves That's the property of *internal linkage*: it is internal to the translation unit, other translation units can't see it. Placing `LEN` in header, each translation unit has its own distinct copy of `LEN`, and all these copies are internal to the respective translation units.

Comment: @Yves Think in language features, not keywords.